# ソケットなどでXML文書を複数を転送する場合の区切り文字

Tags: xml

ソケットなど、ストリームで複数のXML文書を順次転送する際の定石について質問です。
それぞれのXML文書は互いに関係が無いものである場合、文書の区切りは、それぞれのルートタグで十分だと考えています。

しかし、juliusの仕様を見ると「行頭の'.'」をデータ終端とするようです。このように「特別な区切り文字」のメリットはどのようなものでしょうか？また、この実装は一般的なものでしょうか？このような「特別な区切り文字」を実装すべきかどうか判断しかねているので、みなさんの意見を教えてください。

http://julius.osdn.jp/juliusbook/ja/desc_module.html

Comment: 類似の例として、[ActionScriptのXMLSocket](http://help.adobe.com/ja_JP/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/XMLSocket.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6)もヌル文字で区切られていますね…。

Comment: ほかにも同様の実装はあるのですね。コメントありがとうございました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

メリットはそのjuliusのドキュメントにあるように「クライアントがパーズしやすくする」ことではないでしょうか。思いつく範囲で挙げてみます。

- XML文書を、XML構造の解析（ルート要素の閉じタグの認識）なしで分割できるようになると思います。
- XML文書が、タグが正しく閉じられていないケースや、タグが途中で切れているケースなどでも、終端を見つけてその文書は破棄し、次の文書の処理に移れそうです。
- SAXモデルではなく、文書全体が揃ってからまとめて解析する、DOMモデルでも扱えそうです。

3点目は「その方が[DOCTYPE宣言](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms256059.aspx)の扱いや、文書のバリデーションなどはしやすいかも」ぐらいですが、1、2点目については、流されるデータが「常に正しいこと」を期待するのもちょっとリスキーかも、という気がします。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
流されるデータが「常に正しいこと」をのくだりが一番説得力を感じました。
ほかのかたも書かれているとおり、それほど特殊な実装でもなさそうなので「XML文書の上位レイヤー」として「特別な区切り文字」を検討したいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

SMTPの本文送信の決まりがまさしくこれです。
パースしやすいというか、明確にブロックが終わりとわかれば受信スレッドとパーススレッドを分けることができるのでパフォーマンスは上がるでしょう。
必要性を感じないなら無理に作ることはないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
なるほど。パーサーのレイヤー分けできますね。
参考にさせていただきます。